# How to select first element in array in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

```
<user-avatar mode="plain" name="[[item.from]]"></user-avatar>
```

item.from is Array. I want to select first element of item.name array

```
<user-avatar mode="plain" name="[[item.from[0].name]]"></user-avatar>
```

instead of using filter function. How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly add the index to the path ([docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#path-binding)).

```
<user-avatar mode="plain" name="[[item.from.0.name]]"></user-avatar>
```